# Использование кастомного минимизатора в SciPy с минимайзером shgo

Tags: python, scipy

Я написал кастомный минимайзер и теперь не могу понять как правильно его вызвать. Вызываю следующим образом:

```
res = optimize.shgo(func=f, bounds=b, n=5, iters=5, minimizer_kwargs={'method':custom})
```

При вызове минимайзера таким образом получаю следующую ошибку:

> ```
> File "...\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_shgo.py", line 576,   
>   in __ init __
>   self.min_solver_args += solver_args[method.lower()]
>
> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'lower'
> ```

Как правильно вызвать кастомный минимайзер?

Answer (score 0):

Напишите `'custom'` (в апострофах):

```
res = optimize.shgo(func=f, bounds=b, n=5, iters=5, 
                    minimizer_kwargs={'method': 'custom'})
```

Comment: Я уже пробовал данный способ, не помогает. Мой минимайзер реализован в виде функции. Если взять в апострафы его, то возникает ошибка:

`    self.min_solver_args += solver_args[method.lower()]
KeyError: 'custom' `

Comment: «Мой минимайзер реализован в виде функции» - но и имя этой функции **нужно** задать как строку.

Comment: К ошибке: Вы наверно заметили, что текст ошибки теперь другой - из него вытекает, что нет функции с именем `custom` - после `'method':` ожидается **строка** с именем **функции**. Например `'SLSQP'`.

Comment: Я усомнился в реализации функции и попытался проделать тоже самое с функцией, которую взял с сайта scipy, возникают те же ошибки, что и у меня. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#custom-minimizers взял данную функцию.

Comment: Ошибка не в реализации функции, но в её **применении** — на вашей ссылке нету параметра `minimizer_kwargs` в `optimize.shgo()`.

Comment: Да, я это понимаю потому и задал вопрос как правильно вызвать кастомный минимайзер для `optimize.shgo` .

Comment: Какое имя вашего кастомного минимайзера?

Comment: Для примера здесь я написал custom, чтобы было проще будем считать, что я использовал минимайзера из примера по ссылке выше и он называется fixedsteps.

Comment: Он называется `custmin`, а не `fixedsteps`. ;-)

Comment: Хорошо, но это не меняет сути вопроса и к сожалению не решает его :(  Мне хочется понять принцип вызова кастомного минимайзера для `optimize.shgo`.

Comment: Смотрю на этот `custmin`, но не вижу в нем ключевого параметра `method=` - вот ваша ошибка!

Comment: Но ведь `custmin` сам и является методом минимизации. По вашему в каком месте там должен быть `mehtod=` ? Я все таки предполагаю, что ошибка кроется именно в том, как он передается в `optimize.shgo()`

Comment: Возможно применить только список с ключами соответствующими ключевым параметром, т.е. например  `minimizer_kwargs={'maxfev': 50, 'stepsize': 0.2}`.

Comment: Извините за то, что у нас возникает недопонимание и обсуждение такое затянутое, я кратенько и примерно объясню принцип работы `optimize.shgo`, сначала берется` n*iters*dim` точек в заданных `bounds` промежутках, затем точки которые претендуют на глобальный минимум отправляются в минимайзер(по дефолту вроде `BFGS`), мне нужно отправить эти точки в свой кастомный минимайзер, допустим это будет `custmin`. Я не понимаю как правильно это сделать. В примере предполагается сценарий использования с `basinhopping`, но в нем также метод поиска локального минимума передается через `minimizer_kwargs`

Comment: Нужно понять — ваш минимайзер не возможно передать функции `optimize.shgo()` - она использует свой собственный минимайзер `scipy.optimize.minimize`.

Comment: В таком случае вопрос наверное можно закрывать, если это действительно так. Придется искать другие пути решения моих задач. Спасибо за потраченное время.

Comment: Не стоит, много счастия!